# Hector_quadrotor doesn't respond to "rostopic pub" command

Tags: hector-quadrotor

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Everyone,
I installed the hector_quadrotor package from source then I ran "roslaunch hector_quadrotor_demo indoor_slam_gazebo"
Finally, I tried to input command velocity using the "rostopic pub" but the quadrotor doesn't respond to the command velocity. I verified via "rqt_graph" that gazebo is connected to the correct topic (/cmd_vel ) and via "rostopic echo /cmd_vel" that data is published to the right topic.
I am using 1.9Gazebo&Gazebo-ROS-packs and hydro ROS installed from binaries for this simulation.

Thank you for any help with this issue

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/162221/hector_quadrotor-doesn%27t-respond-to-%22rostopic-pub%22-command/) by [Robert1](https://answers.ros.org/users/12391/robert1/) on ROS Answers with karma: 63 on 2014-05-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found my mistake. The motor engine didn't start since i didn't provide positive linear velocity on  the "z" direction. Now it is flying.

---

Originally posted by [Robert1](https://answers.ros.org/users/12391/robert1/) with karma: 63 on 2014-05-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0